# Formula to find possible number of combinations

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

> A committee of 5 is to be selected from a group of 6 men and 9 women. If the selection is made randomly, what is the probability that the committee consists of 3 men and 2 women.

We can solve this problem easily with by **considering unordered selection**:
$$\frac{\binom{6}{3}\binom{9}{2}}{\binom{15}{5}}=\frac{240}{1001}=0.239$$

The same can be found my **considering ordered selection** of group members.
So if first three are all men and next two are women, then there will be $6.5.4.9.8$ such combinations. All such arrangements are shown below

```
| 98 | 6 |    | 5 |    | 4 |    |
|    | 6 | 98 | 5 |    | 4 |    |
|    | 6 |    | 5 | 98 | 4 |    |
|    | 6 |    | 5 |    | 4 | 98 |
| 9  | 6 | 8  | 5 |    | 4 |    |
| 9  | 6 |    | 5 | 8  | 4 |    |
| 9  | 6 |    | 5 |    | 4 | 8  |
|    | 6 | 9  | 5 | 8  | 4 |    |
|    | 6 | 9  | 5 |    | 4 | 8  |
|    | 6 |    | 5 | 9  | 4 | 8  |
```

Hence there are 10 such arrangements. So total possible selections = $6.5.4.9.8.10$
The sample space will be selection of 5 people from 15: $15.14.13.12.11$
So the desired solution is $$\frac{6.5.4.9.8.10}{15.14.13.12.11}=0.239$$

So both ways (considering ordered / unordered selection) gives same solution.
*This is true about all such kinds of questions*.

- My main question is how can I find number of groups that can be formed in such problems. Is there any generalised formula? My guess is we can do this only by as follows : $\binom{4}{1}+\binom{4}{2}=10$. However this way of computing number of groups turns tedious when number of selections out of certain group increases. For example, in above problem, if out of 9 women, we have to select 3 then we can perform selections as follows:

  ```
  | 987 | 6 |     | 5 |     | 4 |     |
  |     | 6 | 987 | 5 |     | 4 |     |
  |     | 6 |     | 5 | 987 | 4 |     |
  |     | 6 |     | 5 |     | 4 | 987 |
  | 98  | 6 | 7   | 5 |     | 4 |     |
  | 98  | 6 |     | 5 | 7   | 4 |     |
  | 98  | 6 |     | 5 |     | 4 | 7   |
  |     | 6 | 98  | 5 | 7   | 4 |     |
  |     | 6 | 98  | 5 |     | 4 | 7   |
  |     | 6 |     | 5 | 98  | 4 | 7   |
  | 9   | 6 | 87  | 5 |     | 4 |     |
  | 9   | 6 |     | 5 | 87  | 4 |     |
  | 9   | 6 |     | 5 |     | 4 | 87  |
  |     | 6 | 9   | 5 | 87  | 4 |     |
  |     | 6 | 9   | 5 |     | 4 | 87  |
  |     | 6 |     | 5 | 9   | 4 | 87  |
  | 9   | 6 | 8   | 5 | 7   | 4 |     |
  | 9   | 6 | 8   | 5 |     | 4 | 7   |
  | 9   | 6 |     | 5 | 8   | 4 | 7   |
  |     | 6 | 9   | 5 | 8   | 4 | 7   |
  ```

  Number of above arrangements can be calculated as follows without enumeration: $\binom{4}{1}+\binom{4}{2}+\binom{4}{2}+\binom{4}{3}=20$. I want to know if there is any generalized formula for this calculation?
- Also I want to know why both (ordered selection and unordered selection) approaches results in same probabilities (in above problem 0.239) for all such kind of problems? I am confused since ordered selection sounds more related to permutations while unordered selection like combination, still they result in same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both reasoning's are right, in your case, note that you don't need to (tediously) calculate all the possible paces for men and women to be chose, you can just use ${5 \choose 2}$ which is  the number of ways you can chose a place for the women.

Note that

$$ \frac{\binom{6}{3}\binom{9}{2}}{\binom{15}{5}} = \frac{\frac{6!}{3!}\frac{9!}{7!}}{\frac{15!}{10!}} {5\choose 2}$$

where on the right side you have chosen in order the places for men and women $\frac{6!}{3!}\frac{9!}{7!}$ and then you have considered all mixing that is possible among the places ${5\choose 2}$

Note that $20 = {6\choose 3}$.

**remark** Assume you have $M$ men and $W$ women and you want to make groups with $m$ men and $w$ women.

you just need to calculate the number of groups.

1) fix the order $\frac{M!}{(M-m)!}\frac{W!}{(W-w)!}$ groups of $\frac{(M+W)!}{M+W -(m+w)!}$

2) consider the different places for the women ${m+w \choose w} = \frac{m+w!}{m! w!}$

3) compute the ratio

$$ \frac{\frac{M!}{(M-m)!}\frac{W!}{(W-w)!}}{\frac{(M+W)!}{M+W -(m+w)!}}\frac{(m+w)!}{m! w!} =\frac{\frac{M!}{(M-m)!m!}\frac{W!}{(W-w)!w!}}{\frac{(M+W)!}{(M+W -(m+w))!(m+w)!}} =  \frac{{M\choose m}{W\choose w}}{{M+W\choose (m+w)}}$$

Comment: ohh yess I was guessing it is star and bar formation. Thats great and easy. So first question is answered. But I am not able to understande: *chosen in order the places for men and women $\frac{6!}{3!}\frac{9!}{7!}$ and then you have considered all mixing that is possible among the places ${5\choose 2}$* . Can you elaborate a more?

Comment: I edited it to provide an explanation for the general formula

Comment: hey daaaamn thanks @Conrado. That was a precise answer explaining the equivalence between ordered and unordered selection **mathematically**. Just want to know, if there is any **logically intuitive** (possibly one line) interpretation explaining why unordered and ordered selection approaches are equivalent.

Comment: Well in one line, it seems that if you force the groups to be taken in order, you need to count the rearrangements you left out, in the example that is just ${5\choose 2}$ factor that you need to take into account.

Comment: Yess, I understand that, and it leads to following term in RHS: $\frac{M!}{(M-m)!}\frac{W!}{(W-w)!}\frac{(M+W)!}{M+W -(m+w)!}$. But am not asking about this. Am asking about the logical (not mathematical reasoning which you already gave in answer) reasoning behind the equivalence: $\frac{\frac{M!}{(M-m)!}\frac{W!}{(W-w)!}}{\frac{(M+W)!}{M+W -(m+w)!}}\frac{(m+w)!}{m! w!}  =  \frac{{M\choose m}{W\choose w}}{{M+W\choose (m+w)}}$. Thus I want to replace the rearranging $m,n,W,M$ done in middle fraction (of last line of your answer) with some wordly logic.

Comment: Or may be just leave it, I may be thinking unnecessarily and we have to prove it mathematically only. There might not be wordly-non numeric/mathematical logic to prove that equivalence.

Comment: sorry I may irritate you...but just want to know more. Order counting approach to solution looks fine to me since we actually go on counting the selection orders. However, unordered selection takes into account only combinations $\binom{n}{r}$, not the selection orders, still it results same. I can see how mathematically the two equates, but cant form the verbal intuitive logic about why $\binom{n}{r}$ approach works. Getting this will help me to generalize type of such problems and recognize that they can be solved in these two ways.

Comment: For eg, this problem can also be solved in similar two ways, but a bit different (there is non $\binom{n}{r}$ term $2^5$ in numerator of Sol 1): *5 people are to be randomly selected from 10 married couple. What is the probability that 5 selected are unrelated?* **Sol 1.** $\frac{\binom{10}{2}2^5}{\binom{20}{5}}=0.52$ **Sol 2.**  $\frac{20.18.16.14.12}{20.19.18.17.16}=0.52$